# Call a WinForm procedure from embedded Cefsharp browser

Tags: javascript, winforms, chromium, cefsharp

I am creating a WinForm app, which contains an embedded browser showing OSM map with the help of Leaflet framework. On the WinForm side there are charts, which have to be updated depending on user-selected marker on OSM map. The interaction between browser and winform is running well as long as I use the native browser in Visual Studio. But due to the poor rendering of huge number of markers in IE I was forced to switch to Chromium with the help of Cefsharp.

Cefsharp version, which I am using is 3.3239.1723.g071d1c1. There were no issues in deploying the browser (theChrisKent tutorial helped a lot - [link](https://thechriskent.com/2014/08/18/embedded-chromium-in-winforms/)).

**The main issue which I am facing is how to call a Winform procedure from JS within Cefsharp/Chromium browser.**

When using the native browser control in VS this can be done pretty easy, but I guess in Cefsharp the approach is completely different. I was reading the docs and some available questions in the net, but I couldn't find my answer. Probably I need to expose a .NET class to JavaScript as per the Docs. To be honest I cannot understand how to do it. On the top of that I am using Visual Basic.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Below I can show very simplified what I need. JavaScript onClick event should fire the execution of WinForms HelloWorld() procedure.

```
//JavaScript side
<script>
    function onClick(e) {
       //How to Call Winform sub HelloWorld?
       //with native browser this is done with "window.external.HelloWorld();"
    };
```

WinForm looks like following:

```
Imports CefSharp.WinForms
Imports CefSharp

Public Class Form1

Private WithEvents browser As ChromiumWebBrowser

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    Dim settings As New CefSettings()
    CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings)

    browser = New ChromiumWebBrowser("http://localhost") With {
    .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    }
    panBrowser.Controls.Add(browser)

End Sub

Private Sub HelloWorld()

    MsgBox("Hello World")

End Sub

End Class
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#3-how-do-you-expose-a-net-class-to-javascript and https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2246 The documentation will be updated soon, until then you'll have to piece it together. There are no official examples in VB.Net.

Comment: Thanks @amaitland for pointing me out that there is a new binding method. I made some research and found out how to implement what I needed. I will post it as self-answer to my question. Cefsharp project is really awesome :) and cheers for your contribution to it!

Answer (score 0):

After amaitland pointed me out in the comments that there is a new binding methodology in the latest version of Cefsharp I made some additional research and found a solution to my problem. Below is the code for calling a VB procedure "showMessage" from JavaScript running in embedded Cefsharp browser. This procedure will write a string value passed from JS to a TextBox in Winform. Hope this could be helpful to someone.

**JavaScript side**

```
function onClick(e) {

    var popup = e.target.getPopup();
    var content = popup.getContent();

    // calling starts here
    (async function() {
    await CefSharp.BindObjectAsync("boundAsync", "bound");
    // "showMessage" is the VB procedure to call in a class "boundAsync"
    boundAsync.showMessage(content);
})();
    // calling ends here

};
```

**VB side**

```
Imports CefSharp.WinForms
Imports CefSharp

Public Class Form1

Private WithEvents browser As ChromiumWebBrowser

// row below is needed for communication between the new class and Form1
Friend Shared MyInstance As Form1

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        Dim settings As New CefSettings()
        CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings)

        browser = New ChromiumWebBrowser("localhost") With {
        .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        }

        panBrowser.Controls.Add(browser)
        // add this line for registering a new class boundAsync
        browser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register("boundAsync", New BoundObject(), True)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        // row below is needed for communication between the new class and Form1
        MyInstance = Me

    End Sub

End Class

// declare the new class
Public Class BoundObject

    // declare the procedure called by JS
    // in this example a value passed from JS is assigned to a TextBox1 on Form1
    Public Sub showMessage(ByVal msg As String)

        If (Form1.MyInstance IsNot Nothing) AndAlso Not Form1.MyInstance.IsDisposed Then

            If Form1.MyInstance.TextBox1.InvokeRequired Then
                Form1.MyInstance.TextBox1.Invoke(New Action(Of String)(AddressOf showMessage), msg)
            Else
                Form1.MyInstance.TextBox1.Text = msg
            End If

        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You are also trying to bind an object called bound, which is probably just a copy and paste mistake. If you are only accessing the object from an event handler then you can probably register it in a J's block in the header and not worry about awaiting for binding completion.

Comment: At some point I'll probably add a helper method for registering events, it might look something like https://gist.github.com/amaitland/48adad9c7f2c57f6c17fad39b2747d00 doesn't quite suite your use case, just posting as a reference.